# NVM Express Submission Queue Entry Command Format

Tags: linux, nvm, pci-e, solid-state-drive

In NVMe Command format of Submission queue it says Metadata Pointer (MPTR) contains an address of a single contiguous physical buffer that is byte aligned. I am not understanding about this Metadata is whose? Is it the metadata of any file for which i have issued read/write/flush command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the NVMe Spec 1.2, section 5.16 concerning the NVMe Format command, only DWORD 10 is utilized and all other fields are reserved.  This means that the Metadata pointer (i.e CDW4 and CDW5) is reserved and should be initialized to 0.  It is important to set CDW1 (ie. the NameSpace ID) to the NameSpace which you want to format (or can be set to 0xFFFFFFFF if the NVMe controller supports formatting of ALL Namespaces).  And, as is always the case with NVMe Admin commands, you must set CDW0 to indicate which Admin Command you are issuing (i.e. you set the OPC field to 0x80 to indicate you are issuing a Format NVMe command)